# Updating nested array mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I think there are multiple ways to do this, and that has me a little confused as to why I can't get it to work.

I have a schema and I would like to update Notes within it but I can't seem to do it. Additionally, if I want to return the notes how would I go about doing it?

schema :

```
{
    _id : 1234 
    email : me@me.com 
    pass : password  
    stock : [ 
        {
        Ticker : TSLA 
        Market : Nasdaq 
        Notes : [ 
            "Buy at 700", 
            "Sell at 1000"
            ] 
        },
        {
        Ticker : AAPL 
        Market : Nasdaq 
        Notes : [ 
            "Buy at 110", 
            "Sell at 140"
            ] 
        },
    
    ]
}
```

Each user has a list of stocks, and each stock has a list of notes.

Here is what I have tried in order to add a note to the list.

```
router.post(`/notes/add/:email/:pass/:stock/:note`, (req, res) => {
    var email = req.params.email
    var pass = req.params.pass
    var note = req.params.note
    var tempStock = req.params.stock 


    userModel.findOne({email: email} , (err, documents)=>{
        if (err){
            res.send(err); 
        }
        else if (documents === null){
            res.send('user not found'); 
        }else if (bcrypt.compareSync(pass , documents.pass)){
            userModel.findOneAndUpdate({email : email , "stock.Ticker" : tempStock}, {$push :  {Notes : note}} ,(documents , err)=>{
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }else {
                    res.send(documents.stock);
                }
            })
          
        }
    })
  

})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: So there is no error, but it just isn't updating and adding the note to my notes. It is not making any changes to my db.

Comment: First check `findOne({email : email , "stock.Ticker" : tempStock})` is it returning result?

Comment: that works. i did res.send(documents) and it sent me the entire userModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you are pushing the new note into a newly created `Notes` property inside the model instead of into the `Notes` of the concrete `stock`. I am not completely aware of the mongoose semantics but you need something like this:

```
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email, "stock.Ticker": tempStock }, { $push: { "stock.$.Notes": note } }, (documents, err) => {
```

`$` gives you a reference to the currently matched element from the `stock` array.

For the second part, I am not sure what you mean by

> Additionally, if I want to return the notes how would I go about doing it?

They should be returned by default if you're not doing any projection excluding them.

Also, as per the docs(and general practise), the callback for the `findOneAndUpdate` has a signature of

`(error, doc) => { }`

instead of

`(documents, err) => { }`

so you should handle that.